# Sox audio concatenation file length wrong

Tags: audio, wav, pcm, sox, audio-processing

I am trying to concatenate multiple audio files using Sox. Each file is very hi-res: 4ch, PCM, 256k sampling (yes, not a typo), 24 bit. Each file is approx 2 mins long. I can concatenate up to 9 files successfully with: `sox file1.wav file2.wav file3.wav outfile.wav`.

After 9 files I have the following sox summary which is correct:

```
Channels       : 4
Sample Rate    : 256000
Precision      : 24-bit
Duration       : 00:21:33.89 = 331236000 samples ~ 97041.8 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 3.97G
Bit Rate       : 24.6M
Sample Encoding: 24-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

When I add a 10th ~2 minute file I get:

```
Channels       : 4
Sample Rate    : 256000
Precision      : 24-bit
Duration       : 00:00:25.18 = 6445658 samples ~ 1888.38 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 4.37G
Bit Rate       : 1.39G
Sample Encoding: 24-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

You'll note here that we went from a length of 00:21:33.89 to a length of 00:00:25.18 with a corresponding drop in samples. Expected result would be a file of ~00:23:xx.xx with the 2 minutes added. The actual file size grew from 3.97GB to 4.37GB so the data is there, it appears to be a problem in the header.

Does anyone know of an upper limit in sox that we might be meeting?

Alternatively does anyone know how I might fix the file post facto? I tried `sox --ignore-length infile.wav outfile.wav` but the output file was identical.

Thanks